# Imported time-lapse from bike ride does not sync with G-Metrix data in VIRB Edit

Tags: movie

I have imported a time-lapse (1 frame/sec resolution) video from my GoPro Hero4 into VIRB Edit.  It's from a 96 minute bike ride, which shows up as a 4 minute video.

When I import G-Metrix (GPX) data from my Garmin Fenix 5, it does not align with the video.   It sees it as a 4 minute bike ride.

How to make VIRB Edit properly recognize the video as a time-lapse?  Or how do I "compress" the GPX so that it matches the video?

Comment: I suspect this might be better on https://video.stackexchange.com/ because its a question about video production and software.